# how to pass the user-defined macro to xcodebuild?

Tags: c, xcode, macros, xcodebuild

I build my project by xcodebuild in command line. Not in xCode. I want to pass some marc to the project so that it can affect the code.  Such as code below:

```
#if (API_TYPE == 1)
  #define URL_API @"https://dapi.xxx.com/1.1/"
#elif (API_TYPE == 2)
  #define URL_API @"https://tapi.xxx.com/1.1/"
#elif (API_TYPE == 3)
  #define URL_API @"https://api.xxx.com/1.1/"
#else
  #error "API_TYPE value error! should be only value 1,2,3 !"
#endif
```

I want pass the define of API_TYPE outside the code files. Such as through xcodebuild command.
But It doesn't work like this:

```
xcodebuild -sdk xxx -target xxx SYMROOT=${XCSYMROOT} API_TYPE=${APITYPE}
```

The API_TYPE's value was not changed. But the SYMROOT's value was changed.
So how can I implement that passing the value to API_TYPE outside ?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but why not just use:

```
xcodebuild GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS API_TYPE=1'
```

If you want to be able to have it optionally override an existing define in app, just code something like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_API_TYPE 1

#ifdef API_TYPE
  #define REAL_API_TYPE API_TYPE
#else
  #define REAL_API_TYPE DEFAULT_API_TYPE
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

The command-line setting you used effectively set an environment variable, at least within Xcode’s build environment. But that build environment does not get passed into the compiler’s preprocessor, just as setting a shell environment variable does not make that environment variable visible in the preprocessor.

To make it visible in the preprocessor, add an entry in the Preprocessor Macros build setting for the project, or for the specific targets you want. The entry should have the form “FOO=$(FOO)”. Xcode passes this to the compiler as “-DFOO=*value of FOO from environment*”.

When editing the Preprocessor Macros setting, be sure you are editing it for All Configurations (or the configuration you want to set it for, if you do not want to set it for all).

Comment: I can get the define of API_TYPE. But I can't change the define value of it. Such as SYMROOT.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your comment. Are you having a problem entering the text “API_TYPE=$(API_TYPE)” into the Preprocessor Macros build setting?

Comment: I enter the text "API_TYPE=0 DEBUG=1" in debug config in xcode project setting. But in command line using xcodebuild, such as command below:" APITYPE=2   xcodebuild -sdk xxx -target xxx SYMROOT=${XCSYMROOT} API_TYPE=${APITYPE} "  It likes the value 2 wasn't passed to xcodebuid command for building .  The API_TYPE=1 value affect the building result.

Comment: In the command line, use “xcodebuild -sdk xxx -target xxx SYMROOT=xxx API_TYPE=xxx”, where each “xxx” is replaced with the value you want. E.g., use “API_TYPE=2”. Do not use “API_TYPE=${APITYPE}”. In the Xcode project, you must set the Preprocessor Macros build setting. You should use the Xcode application for this. You must find the Preprocessor Macros build setting, and you must add an entry that says “API_TYPE=$(API_TYPE)” (note: parentheses, not braces). Do not enter “API_TYPE=0 DEBUG=1” on one line in the Preprocessor Macros build setting. If you want to set 2 items, you must use 2 lines.

Comment: It can solve my problem partly.  I can get API_TYPE value form environment. But when I build it in Xcode, it can't recognize the "$(API_TYPE)" for it was used by enviroment.

Comment: I solve the problem in another way. I set the OTHERCFLAG values -DAPI_TYPE in buildsetting of xcodebuild. The value of OTHERCFLAG is easy to modify.  Thank you very much for answering my questions. Thanks again!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Will you be able to help me on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649972/read-user-defined-macro-from-xcode-build-settings